# Enviar varios valores de checkbox para o banco dados

Tags: php, javascript, html

Eu estou com um problema de lógica, na verdade e não consigo evoluir o que preciso fazer com um código. Segue descrição do problema:

**Problema:**

Eu tenho uma lista de produtos e preciso informar em uma tela se o produto está em *Promoção* ou não. 
Para isso eu escolhi fazer `checkbox` onde o valor 1 é **Permitir** e valor 0 é **Não Permitir** (unchecked). No banco de dados, na tabela *Produtos* eu tenho uma coluna chamada *isPromotion* que recebe esses 0 ou 1. 
O problema é que eu preciso referenciar em qual produto aquele valor será atribuido, então eu coloquei junto de cada produto, um `input` do tipo `hidden` contendo o valor do id de cada produto, algo comum quando montamos essas telas.

```
<input type="hidden" name="idProduto[]" value="<?= $Produto->id; ?>">
```

Agora, supomos que eu queira marcar 5 produtos como *Promoção*, eu vou marcar a checkbox de cada produto e com isso adicionar a um array de dados. Então cada produto tem um `input` do tipo `checkbox` cujo `name` é declarado como um array, veja abaixo:

```
<input class="form-check-input" name="promotion[]" type="checkbox" <?= $Produto->isPromotion != 1 ? 'checked' : ''; ?> value="<?= $Produto->isPromotion ; ?>">
```

Agora temos 2 array: um com os valores de Promoção e o outro com os IDS do produto correspondente.

Aí vem minhas dúvidas e problemas com a lógica: 
O array de IDS envia todos os IDS dos produtos porque ele já vem setado no input, então é obvio que o array retornará todos os IDS, e já o Array de valores da Promoção retorna True or False.

Como eu posso enviar esses valores (Permitir / Não permitir) para o banco de dados, CADA QUAL EM SEU REGISTRO do banco? 
Eu não tenho muito código, e já tentei algumas gambiarras para fazer funcionar mas desisti porque ia ficar horrível.

Aceito qualquer ideia, e por favor, evite postar comentários de outras perguntas. Eu sei selecionar varios valores de checkbox e enviar para o banco de dados. O meu problema é como eu faço para que cada produto que tenha seu próprio checkbox e seu valor seja enviado para o Banco de Dados em seu respectivo registro.

Eu não sei se fui muito claro, mas estou à disposição caso necessitem de mais informações;

Obrigado a todos que puderem ajudar! Grato :)_

Comment: De uma olhada na propriedade [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset). Essa propriedade permite ligar dados arbitrários aos elementos HTML. Pode ser usada para vincular pIds, preços, quantidades, **promoções**,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, não sei se compreendi direito se é exatamente isso que você quer, mas eu fiz rapidinho aqui um código para percorrer a quantidade de input's que você terá criado no seu Form e identificar os valores de cada um, assim jogando todos para o seu Banco de maneira " separada " por linhas. Vai ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
$id_pedido = $connect->insert_id;
$qtd_input = sizeof($_POST['idProduto']);

if(!empty($_POST['idProduto']) || !empty($_POST['promotion'])){
    for($i = 0 ; $i < $qtd_input; $i++) {
        $checkbox = isset($_POST['promotion']);

        $id = $_POST['idProduto'][$i];
        $promo = $checkbox[$i];

        $query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ('{$id_pedido}', '{$id}', '{$promo}')";

        if(!$connect->query($query) === true)
            die("Erro na inserção dos dados <br>" . $connect->error);
    }
}
```

Com a função `sizeof` você consegue verificar o tamanho de um elemento ou objeto a qual ele está procurando, que no seu caso é um input. De acordo com a quantidade de inputs criados com o name `idProduto` ele vai percorrer o valor de cada um com o nome de `idProduto[]` e `promotion[]`, pegando seus valores e jogando separadamente para o Banco ( está é a função que aquele `[$i]` está executando no código.

OBS: Não sei se você fará via `$_GET` ou `$_POST`, qualquer coisa é só alterar.

Edit: Como eu disse no comentário, seria interessante você ter essa tabela em seu Banco com uma Chave Estrangeira vindo de uma outra tabela, como por exemplo, a "Pedido", onde ele puxe o ID do Pedido como chave Primária, com isso, quando o código rodar em todos os `idProduto[]` ele irá jogar cada ID em uma linha no Banco, mas sempre referencia de qual Pedido este pertence, essa séria a função do `$id_pedido` no código. E a respeito de verificar qual checkbox está marcando ou não, você pode verificar isso com o `isset()`, caso ele esteja marcado ele manda o valor para o banco, caso não, ele não manda. Nesse caso, você pode até fazer uma modificação na verificação, e caso não esteja marcado você seta o valor deste como 0, assim você saberá quais estavam marcados ou não.

Comment: Então meu brother, valeu pelo código, não cheguei a testar mas vou, mas olhando por cima, não se se fiz algo semelhante. Alem disso, cada produto terá seu próprio ID setado no `input hidden`, então, nesse código aí ele vai rodar 21x (quantidade de produtos na tela que tenho e cada um com seu ID) porém, por padrão, checkbox não marcados não são enviado pelo POST/GET e aí ele vai apenas enviar os marcados e os que não forem enviados, mas forem chamados no PHP vai dar erro "Undefined Offset" e como o $promo é um array, ele não vai atribuir um valor 0 ou '0' nao venha valor do front, entende?

Comment: Esse tem sido um dos problemas q enfrento rsrs

Comment: Cara, para filtrar apenas os checkbox marcados você também pode fazer uma verificação para enviar os valores. E a respeito da quantidade de IDs, é assim mesmo que ele tem que rodar, o interessante é você ter em seu Banco uma espécie de ID primário onde esses IDs de Produtos estejam ligados como uma espécie de Chave Estrangeira, como por exemplo, um ID de Pedido. Vou editar o codigo com a verificação do checkbox.

Comment: Mano, vou tentar suas dicas, blz e retorno pra dizer como foi...

Comment: Brother, vou setar sua resposta como correta porque na parte do back-end esse código realmente funciona, mas reestruturei o front, de Checkbox para Select com Options. Vlww ai pela atenção e ajuda^^